# Does the availability of Braintree v.zero mean the location of the merchant or the buyer?

Tags: paypal, braintree

> Express Checkout via v.zero is available in Australia, Canada, France, Germany, Italy, Japan, Singapore, the United Kingdom, and the United States.

It says that on PayPal's website for the Braintree v.zero integration.

Does this mean that the buyer must be part of one of these countries (or rather, their PayPal account) or that the seller/merchant's PayPal account must be one of these countries?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases, only the seller has to reside in the country listed. However, there are some countries where both the seller and buyer have to be in the same country. A transaction where both the buyer and seller are in the same country is known as "in-country". You can find a list of the currencies that only allow "in-country" transactions by noting the [ones listed with the "in-country only" superscript here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-api-payment-country-currency-support/#paypal-account-payments) from the PayPal developer documentation.